# Android emulator crashing on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

When I try to launch Android emulator, it crashes on Mac OS X. It was working some time ago, but now it isn't and I don't have an idea why.

Crash log: http://pastebin.com/04MjCqaS

Terminal log in verbose mode: http://pastebin.com/L6y6rUr0

Comment: Is this while you try to install your app or when you just start the emulator?

Comment: I am not even able to start the emulator.

Comment: If you have 2 monitors running. The emulators don't appear to work well at all on mac. 

I've taken to using a single monitor for android emulator work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Same issue here, I'm running a mac mini with 8GB of RAM and MacOS Lion. It used to work with the old AVD with some random crashes every now and then but since the last update to APi 17 it's a pain in the neck.

The ADT bundle doesn't work at all. After tweaking the memory limits on eclipse.ini file it throws random memory errors. Also it's not been able to download and install the m2e (maven to eclipse) plugin.

I moved to IntelliJ and I'm able to launch AVD manager but none of the "old" created devices work. If I create a new one and I launch it it works until I close it, then I have to restart the Mac and create a new device. Also it randomly shows errors when I want to delete those old created virtual devices.

Also the DDMS fails to start. I launch it, shows its icon on the Dock but it doesn't respond until I force close.
What a Nightmare.

** EDIT **
I found at android dev bug tracker this issue when you're running 2 screens: [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36959630)

This is happening to me with the android emulator. I solved it like this:
    cd ~/.android/avd
    ls *.avd

Now choose the emulator that is crashing and

```
cd name_of_the_emulator.avd
touch emulator-user.ini
vi emulator-user.ini
```

And now reset window.x, that's window.x=0
exit and run the emulator.

If you move and close the emulator to the secondary screen it will crash the next time you want to run it.

Comment: Thanks! Was driving me crazy! So dumb. Come on Google.

Comment: I've found half a dozen "fixes" for this problem; but yours' is the first that actually worked for me!  Life saver!

Comment: To keep this from recurring I used chmod 555 on the emulator-user.ini file.

Comment: @SemperFly That is an awesome idea, and works great. (although it should *really* be patched in the tools)

Comment: 1.5 years and the bug is still there throwing rocks to our heads. Darn!

Comment: Workaround works great, thanks!  I also updated ```window.y = 0``` just to be safe ;)

Answer (score 26):

**Kill your Docker process**

One problem I have seen multiple time is with Docker. Android Emulator crashes when Docker is running on Mac.

Comment: Same here, I had Docker running and the emulator would not start. After I shutdown Docker the emulator started with no issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent a ton of time trying to figure out why my emulators stopped working suddenly and this fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I was following the PhoneGap "Getting Started" guide for Android, and when I got to "Deploy to Emulator," after I created a new AVD, my Mac would crash and reboot.  I stumbled on this thread, but thought it worth mentioning that what actually solved the problem for me was an Intel patch for the Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager located here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Answer (score 1):

This is because Android SDK use some deprecated libraries of Mac OS X. I have the same problem (sometimes even kernel panic) before I start use android device. Maybe in future versions of Android SDK this problem will be fixed.

Comment: It's quite annoying that even the newest Android 4.2 emulator isn't working. So there is currently no way to run emulator on Mac?

Comment: It run on mac but sometimes crashes. You can increase RAM size to 8 Gb maybe it can help. You can start emulator for not very long period of time and close it when it unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated the Android SDK manager to the latest Android 4.2 (API 17) level updates, and now all my old AVD's crash. The newly created one using API 17 works, however.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. You can try to create a new AVD with the appropriate API level. I am able to run these the first time(s) after creating. That seems to be a memory error.

My AVDs are able to run the first time after reboot. After this they keeps crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using mac 10.6 and 2 monitors one through a usb adapter to HDMI.
I have tried all of this suggestions and nothing did work.
I ended up creating a new user into my mac and with the same android sdk and same eclipse with a new workspace did work.

I'm not sure whether just creating a new workspace would do the tweak, I didn't try it.
for those who come across to this annoy issue worth to try it before switch to a new account.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your emulators from ~/.android/avd

Then create new emulators.